# Help with the following first-order partial differential equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

I am trying to teach myself how to solve first-order PDEs using the method of characteristics, and I would like to solve the following first-order PDE for $u = u \left(x, y, t \right)$:

\begin{align*}
a \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + b u &= f \left(x, t \right) \tag{1}
\end{align*}

where $a$ and $b$ are constants. From the method of characteristics we get:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
& \frac{dt}{ds} &&= a &&\Rightarrow &&t \left(s \right) &&= as + c_{1} \tag{2}\\
& \frac{d y}{ds} &&= 0 &&\Rightarrow &&y \left(s \right) &&= c_{2} \tag{3}\\
& \frac{d x}{ds} &&= y &&\Rightarrow &&x \left(s \right) &&= y s + c_{3} \tag{4}\\
& \frac{d z}{ds} &&= f \left(x,t \right) - bz &&\Rightarrow &&z \left(s \right) &&= e^{-bs} \left[ \int{e^{bs} f \left(x \left(s \right), t \left(s \right) \right) ds} + c_{4} \right] \tag{5}
\end{alignat*}

However, I am unsure of how to proceed from here to obtain $u \left(x, y, t \right)$. In particular, I am confused regarding how to express the integral in the last equality in terms of $x$ and $t$. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

As an aside, I inputted $(1)$ into WolframAlpha, which gave the following:

\begin{align*}
u \left(x,y,t \right) &= e^{\frac{-bx}{y}} \left[\int_{1}^{x}{\frac{e^{\frac{b \xi}{y}} f \left(\xi, t + \frac{a \left(\xi - x \right)}{y} \right)}{y} d \xi} + g \left(y \right) \left(t - \frac{a x}{y} \right) \right] \tag{6}
\end{align*}

Is this correct? I am slightly confused since from $(1)$, $f$ should depend on $x$ and $t$ only; however, from $(6)$ it appears that $f$ depends on $x$, $t$ *and* $y$. Apologies in advance if these questions sound silly.

Kind regards,
Nathan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations $(5)$ and $(6)$ are both correct, however contradictory they may seem.

This is because Eq.$(5)$ is valid only on the characteristic curve but not valid everywhere. Eq.$(6)$ is valid everywhere (any $x,y,t$).

An equivalent but different presentation may be helpful to understand.

$$a \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}  =-bu+ f \left(x, t \right) $$
Your system of ODEs is correct. Written on an equivalent form (Charpit-Lagrange) :
$$ds=\frac{dt}{a}=\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dy}{0}=\frac{du}{-bu+ f \left(x, t \right)}$$
You corectly found the characteristic equation $\quad y=c_2$.

A second characteristic equation comes from solving $\quad \frac{dt}{a}=\frac{dx}{y}=\frac{dx}{c_2}$:
$$t-\frac{ax}{c_2}=c_3.$$
A third characteristic equation comes from solving $\quad \frac{dx}{c_2}=\frac{du}{-bu+ f \left(x, t \right)}$
$$c_2\frac{du}{dx}=-bu+f(x,t)$$
This is a linear first order ODE wrt the unknown function $u(x)$. The solution is:
$$u=e^{-b\frac{x}{c_2}}\int e^{b\frac{x}{c_2}}f(x,t)dx$$
Especially this must be valid on the characteristic curves $y=c_2$ and $t=c_3+\frac{ax}{c_2}$ :
$$u=e^{-b\frac{x}{y}}\int e^{b\frac{x}{y}}f\left(x\:, \left(c_3+\frac{ax}{y} \right)\right)dx$$
With definite integral :
$$u=e^{-b\frac{x}{y}}\left[\int^{\xi=x} e^{b\frac{\xi}{y}}f\left(\xi\:,\left(c_3+\frac{a\xi}{y} \right)\right)d\xi+C \left(c_2,c_3 \right)\right]$$
$$u=e^{-b\frac{x}{y}}\left[\int^x e^{b\frac{\xi}{y}}f\left(\xi\:, \left(t-\frac{ax}{y}+\frac{a\xi}{y} \right)\right)d\xi+C \left(y\:,t-\frac{ax}{y} \right)\right]$$

$$u(x,y,t)=e^{-b\frac{x}{y}}\left[\int^x e^{b\frac{\xi}{y}}f\left(\xi\:, t + \frac{a(\xi-x)}{y}\right)d\xi+C \left(y\:,t-\frac{ax}{y} \right)\right]$$
$C$ is an arbitray function of two variables.

I don't know why WolframAlpha chose $1$  as lower bound for the integral instead $0$ or any other value. So, I let the choice open.

Comment: What do you mean : "which preserves the arguments of $f$ in their original forms" ?